# Java CertPathBuilderException and SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere, sslhandshakeexception

We are getting exception:

```
com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:     java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
```

It is coming while calling third party domain through POST service call from our Java code.
To resolve this we have tried below steps:

1. Retrieving signer certificate from "SSL certificates" tab in WAS console.
2. Tried to update TLS version to 1.2 in the SSL_client_props file.
3. Uploading latest local_policy.jar and US_Export_Policy.jar.
4. Downloading latest certificate from the OpenSSL and uploading to the server.

Also tried by implementing TrustManager in our code to bypass the certificate trust issue.
Please help if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Where did you retrieve the signer certificate into? Which Trust Store?

Comment: Is there an error in the WebSphere logs telling you what trust is missing trust?  If not it kind of suggest to me that the SSLContext used for the outbound connection is not created by WebSphere.

Comment: @dbreaux In the CellDefaultTrsutStore and NodeDefaultTrustStore

Comment: @Alaine Well we can't actually figure out. After implementing some further steps new error is generating along with the above error: "RSA premaster secret error"